# How to parse xml with namespace using android sax parser

Tags: java, android, sax, saxparser

My XML Document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://localhost/someApp" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <entry>
       <id>An ID here</id>
       <content type="application/xml">
           <m:properties>
              <d:Name>The name I want to get</d:Name>
           </m:properties>
       </content>
     </entry>
</feed>
```

I'm able to get "An ID here" from the `id` tag with this code:

```
String ATOM_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
RootElement root = new RootElement(ATOM_NAMESPACE, "feed");
Element entry = root.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE, "entry");
Element id = entry.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE, "id");

id.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
    public void end(String body){
        messages.add(body); // messages = ArrayList<String>
    }
});
```

However, I can't seem to get "The name I want to get".

I added this code:

```
String METADATA_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
String DATASERVICES_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
Element content = entry.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE, "content");
Element properties = content.getChild(METADATA_NAMESPACE, "properties");
Element name = properties.getChild(DATASERVICES_NAMESPACE, "name");
name.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
    public void end(String body){
        messages.add(body);
    }
});
```

but nothing gets added the messages list.

What do I need to do in order to get `d:Name`?

Comment: In the code you've used `"name"`, while the XML has a tag with local name `Name`. Could it be that capital letter? XML is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as G_H pointed out the problem was I wasn't capitalizing `"name"`

This works:

```
Element name = properties.getChild(DATASERVICES_NAMESPACE, "Name"); // 'Name' instead of 'name'
name.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
    public void end(String body){
        messages.add(body);
    }
});
```